# Currency Conversion (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, currency

My currency converter is constantly outputting NaN, instead of the actual conversion.

- Ex: If the user-entered US dollars is 100.00, Canadian Dollar (CAN) is elected, and the exchange rate is "CAD": 1.316853, the resulting converted currency is 131.69

I am tasked with the following:

1. Converts the user-entered US dollars to the selected currency using the rates listed in the `exchangeRates` object. Display the converted currency with two decimal digits.

   - Ex: If the user-entered US dollars is 100.00, Canadian Dollar (CAN) is elected, and the exchange rate is "CAD": 1.316853, the resulting converted currency is 131.69
2. Displays the resulting converted currency by updating the readonly `<input>` element with ID `resultCurrency`
3. Updates the associated label for resultCurrency to the selected currency's full currency name, currency abbreviation in parentheses, and colon

   - Ex: `Canadian Dollar (CAN):`

```
// Initial data for exchange rates
var exchangeRates = {
  "disclaimer": "Usage subject to terms: https://openexchangerates.org/terms",
  "license": "https://openexchangerates.org/license",
  "timestamp": 1534107604,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "BTC": 0.000157753542,
    "CAD": 1.316853,
    "EUR": 0.879353,
    "JPY": 110.46550427,
    "USD": 1,
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Function to update the options in the toCurrency dropdown
  function updateToCurrencyOptions() {
    // Get the select element and empty its current options
    var $toCurrencySelect = $('#toCurrency');
    
    

    // Add the first "Select currency" option
    var $selectOption = $('<option>', {value: '', disabled: true, selected: true}).text('Select currency');
    $toCurrencySelect.append($selectOption);

    // Loop through each currency in the exchange rates object and add an option for it
    for (var currency in exchangeRates.rates) {
      // Get the currency abbreviation and full name
      var abbreviation = currency;
      var fullName = allCurrencies[currency];

      // Create the option element and add it to the select element
      var $option = $('<option>', {value: abbreviation}).text(fullName + ' (' + abbreviation + ')');
      $toCurrencySelect.append($option);
    }
  }

  // Function to convert USD to the selected currency and update the result input and label
  function updateResultCurrency() {
    // Get the amount in USD and selected currency from the inputs
    var usd = $('#usdAmount').val();
    var currency = $('#toCurrency').val();

    // Convert the USD to the selected currency using the exchange rates object
    var rate = exchangeRates.rates[currency];
    var converted = usd * rate;

    // Round the converted amount to 2 decimal places
    converted = Math.round(converted * 100) / 100;

    // Update the result input and label
    $('#resultCurrency').val(converted.toFixed(2));
    var fullName = allCurrencies[currency];
    $('#resultLabel').text(fullName + ' (' + currency + '):');
  }

  // Function to update the exchange rates and dropdown options when the Update Rates button is clicked
  function updateExchangeRates() {
    // Get the new exchange rates from the textarea and parse them as JSON
    var newRatesJson = $('#exchangeRates').val();
    var newRates = JSON.parse(newRatesJson);

    // Update the exchange rates object and the dropdown options
    exchangeRates = newRates;
    updateToCurrencyOptions();

    // Reset the result input and label
    $('#resultCurrency').val('---.--');
    $('#resultLabel').text('To Currency ():');
  }

  // When the page is ready, update the dropdown options and set up the event listeners
  updateToCurrencyOptions();
  $('#toCurrency').change(updateResultCurrency);
  $('#updateRatesButton').click(updateExchangeRates);

});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug this? Have you verified the values of the variables you set in `updateResultCurrency()`?

Comment: Are you getting the base USD value from an `input` element? if so, the value might be by default a `string` even if you set it as `type="number"`. Try converting the input value to `number` by `parseFloat()`, `Number()` or other related methods.